# Does Windows 7 Anytime Upgrade to Professional give downgrade rights?

Tags: windows, license, anytime-upgrade

If I use Windows Anytime Upgrade to upgrade from Win7 Home Premium to Win7 Professional, does that grant me downgrade rights to Windows XP Professional?

Comment: Seems like a round about way of getting Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

http://www.channelregister.co.uk/2009/06/19/windows_7_downgrade_rights_clarity/

Answer (score 0):

It also gives you windows XP, if your CPU supports virtualization.